# Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem for Picard groups of surfaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Griffiths and Harris, *On the Noether-Lefschetz Theorem and Some Remarks on Codimension-Two Cycles*, Math. Ann. 271, 31-51 (1985), states

> [...] look at the restriction
>   $$r_1 : \operatorname{Pic}({\widetilde{S}}) \to \operatorname{Pic}(\widetilde{C})$$
>
> [...]
>
> We make the following observations:
>
> [...]
>
> ii) $r_1$ *is injective*, since the curve $\widetilde{C}$ is a generically chosen hyperplane section of the non-ruled surface $\widetilde{S}$.

on page 36.  (Paper available here: http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/noether.pdf)

**Question**: Why is this true?